# Will .Net Core Tag Helpers work in .html(not .cshtml) pages?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I need to create a reusable widget using .Net core wherein the data of the widget changes based on the input. As per my understanding, these reusable widgets can be created using Tag Helpers. However, I need to place these tag helpers in a .html file instead of .cshtml. Is it possible? If not, what are the other ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share more details about what is your reusable widget?And why do you want to use html file instead of cshtml file?

Comment: The widget is used to display the details of a book. Book name would be the input. A page can contain more than one widget, each corresponding to different books. Displaying it in html file is the requirement.

Comment: Do it in cshtml. Return the view. Basically it will get html page

Answer (score 0):

Tag Helpers are an integral part of the asp.net core razor view engine, and as such, can not be included in a basic html page.  Only cshtml pages.  cshtml files generate html files so you hopefully can figure out a way to get your "widgets" or tag helpers inside a csthtml file. You could use iframes I suppose but that leads to other problems with things like auth.